# How to apply condition on JSONB type column in JOOQ

Tags: java, postgresql, jooq

I am using PostgreSQL and have JSONB type column (reference_object) in Notifications Table. I have to filter the records based on questionId. Question Id is part of the JSON object. I have written below query and it's working fine, but I'm not able to convert it to a jOOQ query.

```sql
SELECT * FROM public.notifications where reference_object ->> 'questionId' ='0e75ce19-d124-4d86-84e8-10362c38c972'
```